# How to distinguish between different Gaussian random number generators

Tags: normal-distribution, random-generation

For example I have 2 different Gaussian random number generators.
The first mathematical expectation is 50 and the variance is 5.
The second mathematical expectation is 60 and the variance is 5.
(Actually I don't know their mathematical expectation and variance)
They generate random signals at the same time.
Maybe the first one produces "46 48 50 49 55 56 53 52". The second produces "60 56 59 62 66 54 59 57". I can only detect jumbled numbers right now, like "46 60", "48 56", "50 59", "49 62", "55 66", "56 54", "53 59", "52 57".

I know this problem can be easily solved by increasing the number of samples. But what I am facing now is to determine the mathematical expectation of these two different random number generators in as few samples as possible.
Is there any algorithm to solve this problem, please.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what "jumbled numbers" are and how they might be related to the random number generators?

Comment: @whuber sorry, my English is not good. in the example, i mean, the first one produces "46 48 50 49 55 56 53 52" in order. and the second one produces "60 56 59 62 66 54 59 57" in order.
what i can get from my hardware is "46 60"........."52 57" in order. the "46 60" is the first number of two sequences. but i can't know 46 or 60 from the first generator or the second one respectively

Comment: It's not clear what you mean. A proper pseudo-random number generator should return independent samples so the order should not matter at all. Do you want to guess which distribution did the numbers come from or you want to validate the quality of the implementation? Those are completely different problems.